# LCM through Prime factorization method in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find the LCM through prime factorization. Here, we have to take the prime factorization of each number, find all the unique primes in all the numbers and raise them to the power where they take the maximum. For example, LCM (12, 18, 24) = LCM(2^2 * 3, 2 * 3^2, 2^3 * 3) So LCM = 2^3 * 3^2

I am trying to save the prime factorization in a list and then run some loop to find all uniqes primes and their respective maximum powers. But I got struck. Any help?

```
RcppAlgos::primeFactorize(12) %>% table %>% as.data.frame()
#. Freq
#2    2
#3    1
```

This is my basic idea but got struck here with how to proceed.

```
find_lcm = function(lcm_list) {
  prime_fact_dictionary = vector("list", length(lcm_list))
  for i in lcm_list {
    prime_fact_dictionary[[i]] = RcppAlgos::primeFactorize(i) %>% 
      table %>% 
      as.data.frame()
    
    ## contd...
  }
}
```

Expected output = 2^3 * 3^2